# c++-default_random_engine creates all the time same series of numbers

Tags: c++, random

I am working with neural networks, and I want to create the weights randomly. SO if I create 30 Neural networks every single one of them ends up having the same weights(supposed to be random) so when i give them all the same input the output is the same, when it shouldn't. Any help?

Here is the main function

```
int main(){
std::vector<Improved_NN> v;
std::random_device rd;
std::default_random_engine generator(rd());
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(-1.0,1.0);
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    Improved_NN temp;
    temp.initialize_weights(generator, distribution);
    v.push_back(temp);
}

Board temp;

for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    std::cout <<"\n" << v[i].executeFromExternal(temp);
}
```

And the initialize_weights is here:

```
 void Improved_NN::initialize_weights(std::default_random_engine gen,std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist){
int k,v = 0;
for(k = 0;k<NUM_HIDDEN_1;k++){
    for(v = 0 ; v < NUM_INPUTS; v++){
        mlp_t.w_h1_i[k][v]=dist(gen);
        //std::cout<<mlp_t.w_h1_i[k][v]<<std::endl;
    }
}
for(k = 0;k<NUM_HIDDEN_2;k++){
    for(v = 0 ; v < NUM_HIDDEN_1; v++){
        mlp_t.w_h2_h1[k][v]=dist(gen);
        //std::cout<<mlp_t.w_h2_h1[k][v]<<std::endl;
    }
}
for(k = 0;k<NUM_HIDDEN_3;k++){
    for(v = 0 ; v < NUM_HIDDEN_2; v++){
        mlp_t.w_h3_h2[k][v]=dist(gen);
        //std::cout<<mlp_t.w_h3_h2[k][v]<<std::endl;
    }
}
    for (int a = 0 ; a < NUM_HIDDEN_3;a++){
        mlp_t.w_o_h[0][a] = dist(gen);
        //std::cout<<mlp_t.w_o_h[0][a]<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

This is the output i get every time i execute.

0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458
0.521458

Thank you very much.

Comment: Build only one generator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, as with plain old `rand()` you need to provide initial seed for the generator which needs to be different value in order for generator to generate different sequence:

```
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine generator(rd());
```

Also, as user3018144 pointed out, use single generator, instead of 30 different:

```
int main(){
    std::vector<Improved_NN> v;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine generator(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(-1.0,1.0);

    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        Improved_NN temp;

        /*Problem is here*/
        temp.initialize_weights(generator, distribution);
        v.push_back(temp);
    }

    Board temp;

    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        std::cout <<"\n" << v[i].executeFromExternal(temp);
    }


//for the number of generations, do this....
}
```

Also, right here:

```
 void Improved_NN::initialize_weights(std::default_random_engine gen,std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist){
```

you're passing the generators by value, which will create a copy of the existing generator. Pass by reference instead:

```
 void Improved_NN::initialize_weights(std::default_random_engine& gen, std::uniform_real_distribution<double>& dist){
```

Comment: Ok now at least it shows difference numbers every execution, but i still get the same 30 outputs(although different for every execution)

Comment: I changed that as well and still have the same result. I edited the question showing how the code looks like now.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation of `<random>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/), it is stated that one has to `bind` the generator to the distribution in order to reuse it.

Here is a small example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::default_random_engine rd;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(-1.0, 1.0);
    auto weight = std::bind(distribution, rd);
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << weight() << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Probably you can adapt it to your case, by passing `weight` (by reference, as @NemanjaBoric has noted) to the `initialize_weights` method.

Here is how to compile and run:

```
c++ main.cpp -o rands -std=c++11 && ./rands
-0.736924 -0.0826997 -0.562082 0.357729 0.869386 0.0388327 -0.930856 0.0594004 -0.984604 -0.866316 0.373545 0.860873 0.0538576 0.307838 0.402381 0.524396 -0.905071 -0.343532 0.512821 -0.269323 0.965101 0.506712 -0.854628 0.769414 -0.127177 -0.0445365 -0.450186 -0.666986 0.795313 -0.878871
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 std::random_device mch;
 std::default_random_engine generator(mch());
 std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

With the same seed, the random engine will generate the same numbers every time.
The usual way to get around this is to use the time() function from the ctime library, as the seed. This works because the time() function returns the time in seconds, hence you get a different number with every second.

In some systems this code will work:

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    default_random_engine gen(time(0));
    // Random number for the range 1-100
    uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(1, 100); 
    for (auto i = 0; i<10; ++i){
        cout << distr(gen)<< endl;
        }
}
```

In some systems there is an issue with this code, regarding the first random number being always the same or differing by just 1. This might be due to the large time value changing by just 1 by every second, hence the seed value being very similar each time.

The way to get around this is by defining the random number so that the call distr(gen) is done multiple times to produce that first random number. This works because for some reason the other random numbers aren't the same, and hence if the first number is defined by getting those other not static numbers into the mix, we can get also the first number changing values.

Here is an example of how one could implement this solution:

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    default_random_engine gen(time(0));
    uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(1, 100); 
    for (auto i = 0; i<10; ++i){
        int random_num = (distr(gen)*distr(gen))/distr(gen);
        // The while loop is to get the number on the 
        // range 0-100. 
        while (random_num > 100){
            if (random_num % 2 == 0){
                random_num = random_num/2;}
            else{
                random_num = (random_num-1)/2;}}
        cout << random_num << endl;
        }
}
```